# How to increase fontWeight of a text for an android app based on React Native?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I'm trying to replicate a web application to an android app.

The application uses `Migra Extralight` font and uses a `fontWeight:500`. Now I tried to use it on my android app using react native but I found out that `fontWeight` isn't supported on Android and it uses custom fonts directly.

Here's what the web app version looks:
[image: Normal Version]

Now this font-family has two versions that are suitable for this. One is `Migra Extralight` and another is `Migra Extrabold` which look like this on the Android app when I try to use them directly:
[image: Migra Extralight]
[image: Migra Extrabold]

As you can see, they don't look like the original at all.

I was thinking of making a custom `fontWeight:500` font by converting it using some software, but couldn't find any. I tried to use `react-native-font-weight` as well but it throws errors while installing because the latest react version which I'm using is unsupported for this library.